# Elements added to array in a function not available in the class, losing its values

Tags: java

My program is supposed to simulate a shopping cart. One of the functions, it reads the item data from text document and stores the data such as price, item id, and item name, in the array. Once I try to access the array contents from the 'myClass' class below, it seems that the array contents that were added in the function disappeared. I was wondering if someone can help me figure out what is the correct way to use idArray which had elements added to it in a function, in myClass as attempted below?

Note: I added comments to the area to the array that isn't printing out as expected below.

I appreciate any help in advance.

```
    public class MyClass extends JFrame{

            public String[] idArray = new String[10];
            public String[] recordArray = new String[10];
            public String[] priceArray = new String[10];

            public void openFile(){
                try{
                    x = new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
                    x.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Could not find file");
                }
            }
            public void readFile(){
                int i=0;
                while(x.hasNext()){
                    idArray[i] = x.next();
                    recordArray[i] = x.next();
                    priceArray[i] = x.next();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            public MyClass(){


                /** Code to create GUI Here    **/


                //Process Item
                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                      String y = item1.getText();
                      int numItems = Integer.parseInt(y);
                      MyClass obj = new MyClass();
                      obj.openFile();

                      //**ARRAY PRINTS OUT NULL AND DOES NOT PRINT OUT THE VALUES AQUIRED IN THE FUNCTION ABOVE**//
                      for(int i=0; i < numItems; i++){
                          for(int g=0; g < idArray.length; g++){
                                System.out.println(obj.idArray[g]);   
                          }
                       }
                   }
                });
         }      
    }
```

Comment: Where does `readFile()` get called?  Where does `x` get defined?  You should add some debug statements to `readFile()` to make sure it's getting executed and to keep track of what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I deleted a lot of code to make it more readable on the site, I defined all my variables including x... The problem was I never called readFile(), silly mistake on my part, I was trying to figure it out for a good while, thanks for pointing that out, I appreciate the help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you never actually call `readFile` so the values are never set. I assume that you were intending to call `readFile` from `openFile`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was exactly my problem, silly mistake. I overcomplicated the problem and have been trying to figure it out for quite a while. I appreciate the help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something it looks like you are opening the file but forgetting to read the file....thus the null.  Try this:

```
   obj.openFile();
   obj.readFile();
```